UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b when paring the downloaded json
trying to parse json file on the web using python, but get into a problem saying :

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position
1: invalid start byte

here is the code
import json
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://a.amap.com/Loca/static/loca-v2/demos/mock_data/sz_road_F.json') as url:
    url_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(url_data)

any idea what is going on with the code ?

Have you looked at the many (possible) duplicates with the same title as your error message that point to the possibility that the data might be gzipped?

Does this answer your question? Decoding urllib.request response

like mentioned in a comment, the data you received is likely compressed, a similar library for making web requests is the requests module and can be used like this. I'm sorry i generally don't use urllib and therefore have no proper answer using that module.
import requests
with requests.get("https://a.amap.com/Loca/static/loca-v2/demos/mock_data/sz_road_F.json") as response:
    url_data = response.json()

